# How to fill data from SQL pivot table in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I have two tables. The values of a column of table1 are used as columns of table2 (transposing row to column). With help of google search, I prepared my SQL query as:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @col1 AS NVARCHAR(30),
        @col2 AS NVARCHAR(30),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT
    @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT',' + QUOTENAME(schedule) 
                   FROM table1 
                   WHERE value = 'value1' 
                   GROUP BY schedule 
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

SET @col1 = 'value1'
SET @col2 = 'value2'

SET @query = N'SELECT eclo1, ecol2, ecol3, ' + @cols + N' FROM  
               (SELECT eclo1, ecol2, ecol3, ecol4, schedule 
                FROM table2 
                WHERE eval1 = ''' + @col1 + ''' AND eval2 =  ''' + @col2 + ''') x
               PIVOT
                   (COUNT(material) FOR schedule IN (' + @cols + N')) p '

EXECUTE(@query)
```

This running fine in SQL Server Management Studio, I want to fill result in my datatable, but don't know how write a `SqlCommand` in my ASP.NET page.

Comment: There are literally thousands of simple examples out there.

Comment: please provide the link of at least example

Answer (score 0):

Chuck all that code into a stored procedure with whichever parameters you need to expose, as parameters to the sproc (col1 and col2?)

```
using var da = new SqlDataAdapter("your_sproc_name_here", ConnectionString));

da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@col1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = "whatever";       
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@col2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = "whatever2";

var dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
```